# GLSL light/highlight moving with camera

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

**VC++ 2010, OpenGL, GLSL, SDL**

I am moving over to shaders, and have run into a problem that originally occured while working with the ogl pipeline. That is, the position of the light seems to point in whatever direction my camera faces. In the ogl pipeline it was just the specular highlight, which was fixable with:

```
glLightModelf(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, 1.0f);
```

Here are the two shaders:

**Vertex**

```
varying vec3 lightDir,normal;

void main()
{
    normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
    lightDir = normalize(vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position));

    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

**Fragment**

```
varying vec3 lightDir,normal;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    vec3 ct,cf;
    vec4 texel;
    float intensity,at,af;

    intensity = max(dot(lightDir,normalize(normal)),0.0);

    cf = intensity * (gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse).rgb + 
                        gl_FrontMaterial.ambient.rgb;
    af = gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse.a;

    texel = texture2D(tex,gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    ct = texel.rgb;
    at = texel.a;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(ct * cf, at * af);  
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is: What coordinate system (reference frame) do you want the lights to be in? Probably "the world".

OpenGL's fixed-function pipeline, however, has no notion of world coordinates, because it uses a *modelview* matrix, which transforms directly from eye (camera) coordinates to model coordinates. In order to have “fixed” lights, you could do one of these:

- The classic OpenGL approach is to, every frame, set up the modelview matrix to be the *view* transform only (that is, be the coordinate system you want to specify your light positions in) and then use `glLight` to set the position (which is specified to apply the modelview matrix to the input).
- Since you are using shaders, you could also have separate model and view matrices and have your shader apply both (rather than using ftransform) to vertices, but only the view matrix to lights. However, this means more per-vertex matrix operations and is probably not an especially good idea unless you are looking for clarity rather than performance.

Comment: Although i found this was not actually my problem, this led me to the right answer. So thank you. (It was a normal mapping issue)